# Formal series expansion of differential operator (d/dx + f(x))^n

Tags: power-series, operator-algebras

My original problem was to find the "coefficient" functions $\varphi_{k,n}(x)$ in

$$
(\partial_x + f(x))^np(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n\varphi_{k,n}(x)\partial_x^kp(x).
$$

(i.e. find the coefficients $\varphi_{k,n}$ in the formal power series expansion in $\partial_x$ of the operator $(\partial_x + f(x))^n$).

Without much difficulty one can find
$$
\varphi_{k,n}(x) = \binom{n}{k}[(\partial_x + f(x))^{n-k}1]
$$

This is not too helpful, however, since now I need $(\partial_x + f(x))^{\mu}1$, for which an expansion in terms of $\partial_x^k\,f(x)$ is impossible due to cross terms. I would love to have a most succinct way of describing $(\partial_x + f(x))^{\mu}1$. At worst I predict that it will end up looking vaguely similar in form (and complexity) to Faà di Bruno's formula for the coefficients in a series of composed functions. At best we may be able to have a closed form for the real numbers that appear in the expression - they seem eerily similar to Stirling numbers of the second kind. Any representation of this,  $(\partial_x + f(x))^{\mu}1$, for arbitrary integral $\mu >0$ and analytic $f$, though, I would be very grateful for. The first few iterations $\mu = 0$ to $\mu = 5$ are given below. Thank you so much for any help whatsoever! 
$$
1\\
f\\
f'+f^2\\
f''+3 f f'+f^3\\
f'''+4 f f''+6 f^2 f'+3 f'^2+f^4\\
f'''' + 5 f''' f + 10 f^2 f'' + 10 f^3 f' + 15 ff'^2 + 10 f' f'' + f^5
$$

PS. In case anyone is interested in context, I need this because I'd like to know, as an 'end-goal', $q(x)$ in $e^{g(x)\partial_x + f(x)}\psi(x) = \psi(q(x))$ given $g$ and $f$. I have already done this for $f = 0$, but more general differential operators involving mixed powers of the derivative are much harder, it seems. Such an expansion would be helpful in proving supporting theorems describing a more general approach to a more general problem that I play with in my spare time.

Comment: what do you mean by $\color{blue}{1}$ here in $
\varphi_{k,n}(x) = \binom{n}{k}[(\partial_x + f(x))^{n-k}\color{blue}{1}]
$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An integrating factor seems to help:
$$ (\partial_{x}+f)g = g'+fg = e^{-\int fdx}\partial_{x}(e^{\int fdx}g)=(e^{-\int fdx}\partial_{x}e^{\int fdx})g, $$
where $e^{-\int fdx}$ is treated as a multiplication operator. Then
$$ (\partial_x+f)^{n} = e^{-\int fdx}\partial_x^n e^{\int f dx}. $$
This helps with your stated end goal. For example, this exponential series looks like a power series, which makes sense for holomorphic functions $f$ and $g$:
$$
    e^{t(\partial_{x}+f)}g=e^{-\int_{0}^{x} f(r)dr}\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{n}}{n!}\partial_{x}^{n}\right]e^{\int_{0}^{x} f(r)dr}g(x) = e^{-\int_{0}^{x} f(r)dr}(e^{\int_{0}^{x+t}f(r)dr}g(x+t))=e^{\int_{x}^{x+t}f(r)dr}g(x+t).
$$
You're looking at the case where $t=1$.
As for your immediate problem,
$$
       (\partial_x+f)^{n}g=e^{-\int fdx}\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}(e^{\int fdx}g) = e^{-\int fdx}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}\left[\frac{d^{n-k}}{x^{n-k}}(e^{\int fdx})\right]\partial_{x}^{k}g.
$$
But it doesn't really help because the coefficients you want are as expected:
$$
              \varphi_{k,n} = {{n}\choose{k}}e^{-\int fdx}\frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}}(e^{\int fdx})={{n}\choose{k}}(\partial_{x}+f)^{n-k}1.
$$
It's explicit, but maybe not so helpful.

These things are related to $C^0$-semigroup theory where one forms $e^{tA}$. Equivalently, you are solving a partial differential equation in $t$ and $x$ because
$$        y(x,t)=e^{tA}u(x) $$
solves
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = Ay,\;\;\; y(x,0)=u(x). $$
In your case, you want $y(x,1)$ where $y(x,t)$ is the solution of
$$
         \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = g\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+fy,\;\;\; y(x,0)=\psi(x). 
$$
This is a first order x-t equation.

Comment: I'm not supposed to use the comments for thanks, apparently, but I definitely want to say thank you! I will be sure to upvote this once I have the privilege. I have come across methods similar to the one you describe using partial differential equations in x and t and then collapsing t to 1, i.e. in the proof of the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff expansion. To be totally fair, I'm just an enthusiastic physics student with a creative itch, but very ignorant to rigorous treatments of newer mathematics. Is there a specific place you might recommend I look for more information on these similar problems?

Comment: The subject of C0 semigroups belongs to the theory of normed-linear spaces and inner-product spaces, though the matrix versions look more classical. Here's a recent survey article that explains how these ideas apply to numerical algorithms, and it helps clarify connections between time-evolution, the exponential, and product-formulas in numerics. http://math.berkeley.edu/~chorin/choma.pdf . Because it's a survey, the references at the end are extensive. They even reference the old 1957 classic of Hille and Philips on semigroup theory, along with more recent research.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts, what do you mean by $\color{blue}{1}$ here in $
\varphi_{k,n}(x) = \binom{n}{k}[(\partial_x + f(x))^{n-k} \color{blue}{1}]
$ ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR : It is an operator acting on the constant function $1$, which has a value of $1$. For example $(\partial_x +f)^21 = (\partial_x^21 + \partial_x(f)+f\partial_x (1)+f^2 1)=0+f'+0+f^2$

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts, ok, I have then a question. Can we expand $(\partial_X+f(x))^n$ expand in Binomial formula? Notice that we can expand $(a+b)^n$ in Binomial formula if $ab=ba$ i.e., commutative but here $\partial_x f \neq f\partial_x$ . So how can we expand the form $(\partial_X+f(x))^n$ ?