# can we have $(\partial _x+f(x))^n=\partial _x^n+\binom{n}{1} (\partial _x)^{n-1}f(x)+\cdots+(f(x))^n$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

We know that $(a+b)^n=a^n+\binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}b+\cdots+b^n$ when $a,b$ commutes to each other.

Am I right?

My question is-

Can we expand $(\partial _x+f(x))^np(x)$ or $(\partial _x+f(x))^n$ in the above formula ?

i.e., can we have $(\partial _x+f(x))^n=\partial _x^n+\binom{n}{1} (\partial _x)^{n-1}f(x)+\cdots+(f(x))^n$ ?

Note that if the field is of characteristic $n$ (prime), then we can have equality.

So when $(\partial _x+f(x))^n$ can be expanded ?

Some hints is given here [Formal series expansion of differential operator (d/dx + f(x))^n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625464/formal-series-expansion-of-differential-operator-d-dx-fxn/625519?noredirect=1#comment6914561_625519)

Comment: The way to see this is by induction. Check what happens when the operator is applied twice, thrice, and try to note the mechanism.

Comment: No, we cannot plug $a = \partial_x$ and $b = f\left(x\right)$ into the binomial formula, since $a$ and $b$ needs to commute ($ab=ba$) for the binomial formula to hold.

Comment: @Allawonder, I think that way says $NO$. But is there any way to expand similarly?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR If it's no, then that's that. What do you mean by *expand similarly?*

Comment: @darijgrinberg, So how to consider series like $\sum (\partial_x+f(x))^np(x)x^n$ and its convergence or divergence?

Comment: @darijgrinberg, I mean if we consider a field of characteristic $n$ (prime) then obviously the equality holds

Comment: @Allawonder,I mean if we consider a field of characteristic $n$ (prime) then obviously the equality holds

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR: I highly doubt that it holds for characteristic $n$.